# I need to develop a power source that delivers adjustable currents in the pA range

Tags: circuit-design, ltspice

The task is to develop a power source that delivers adjustable currents in the pA range.

I need it from my circuit. Also it has to be a consistent power supply.

Here is my circuit.

This is with the output and input voltages:

[image]

Output impedance:

[image]

Input impedance:

[image]

Comment: While I can't figure out how a small signal AC amplifier relates to a pA "power source", here may be a language or terminology problem here. Sources characterised by output current are *current sources*, power depends on load. How does the output current need to be adjusted: Is there a required *transfer function*? What range of loads need to be driven?

Comment: So it is a language/terminology problem, I am studying in german and had to translate some terms. So I still can't answer all your questions, I am still waiting for the professor to reply on those, but I know that it is a current source. not a power source.                       so my previous task was to simulate this circuit with and without the R3 and then check the input/output impendence, once I was done, I was asked to transform it to a current source that has adjustable pA range